# Ricoh Theta Z1 Doesn't Accept My Request to Change File Format

Tags: theta360, ricoh-theta

I am using a Ricoh Theta Z1 updated to the most recent firmware (1.60.1). I am trying to debug an Android application, but I found that one of our commands was repeatedly failing, so I connected to the camera directly from my dev box and tested the protocol directly via curl.

It's my understanding from the documentation that this command should work:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"   -d '{"name":"camera.setOptions", "parameters":{"options":{"captureMode":"image","fileFormat":{"height":3360,"type":"jpeg","width":6720}}}}'   http://192.168.1.1/osc/commands/execute
```

But when I run this command I get this response:

```
{"error":{"code":"invalidParameterValue","message":"Any input parameter or option name is recognized, but its value is invalid."},"name":"camera.setOptions","state":"error"}
```

This in spite of the fact that when I ask the camera about its options, it responds with the exact block it has just told me wouldn't parse:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d '{"name":"camera.getOptions", "parameters":{"optionNames":["clientVersion","captureMode","fileFormat"]}}' http://192.168.1.1/osc/commands/execute
```

gets this response:

```
{"name":"camera.getOptions","results":{"options":{"captureMode":"image","clientVersion":2,"fileFormat":{"height":3360,"type":"jpeg","width":6720}}},"state":"done"}
```

Furthermore, when I run the first command and omit the `fileFormat` parameter, the command executes just fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error, I discovered that it **is** possible to use `camera.setOptions` to set the file format on the camera, but **only** if the `fileFormat` block is the only member of the `options` block. That is to say, this command:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"   -d '{"name":"camera.setOptions", "parameters":{"options":{"fileFormat":{"height":3360,"type":"jpeg","width":6720}}}}'   http://192.168.1.1/osc/commands/execute
```

will succeed. I think this must be a bug in the Theta Z1 camera, because as far as I can discern from the docs (https://api.ricoh/docs/theta-web-api-v2/commands/camera.set_options/ and https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/reference/camera/setoptions), there shouldn't be any restriction on what JSON goes into the `options` block. In any case, the workaround is simple enough: issue one command to set the file format and one or more as necessary to set the other options, and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, there is a similar bug with dateTimeZone.  see this post

https://community.theta360.guide/t/how-setup-datetime-on-theta-camera-using-web-api/6572/3?u=craig

It seems like there are a few options that need to be set as a standalone option.

If you want to set dateTimeZone, it must be the only option set.  I reported this to RICOH.  I am going to post your findings on the community.theta360.guide forum to make it easier to find.  Thanks.